# Is A -> BB valid under Chomsky's normal form?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

> ```
> A → BC,   or
> A → a,   or
> S → ε,
> ```

Above is the typical definition given on Wikipedia and in textbooks.
Nothing i can find says the B and C variables have to be different variables either, but nothing i can find says they can be same definitively . I am leaning towards it being valid but i just want to make sure.

Comment: In general, a definition that requires two names to refer to different objects should say so explicitly. So here $B$ and $C$ can refer to the same variable. In this case, it doesn't really make any significant difference: if you had a production $A \to BB$, you could replace it with a production $A \to BB'$ by adding in copies of all the productions involving $B$ with $B$ replaced by $B'$.

Answer (score 0):

They do not have to be different variables. See, for instance, the final example in [this PDF](https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/cs373/fa2013/Lectures/lec17.pdf), in which a grammar is reduced to a Chomsky normal form that includes a production $X_{aa}\to X_aX_a$.